# Unable to deploy contactlist lwc to dev org

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/schema/ContactController.getContacts';
const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'First Name', fieldName: FIRSTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: LASTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: EMAIL_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'email' }
];

export default class ContactList extends LightningElement {
    columns = COLUMNS;
    @wire(getContacts)
    contacts;
}
```

it calls a Apex code

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(){
       return [
            SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email
            FROM Contact
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
            ORDER BY FirstName
        ];
    }
}
```

while trying to deploy the code to org, I have got the error **Invalid reference ContactController.getContacts of type sobjectClass in file contactList.js**.
The apex code was called correctly but still got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContacts`, not `@salesforce/schema/ContactController.getContacts`, which is used to import object and field references.